# how to create a dynamic link in Django

Tags: django

how can i build dynamic link in Django?
I have a blog and each post need to have a unique link.
content of  blog's post must show on linked page.
I searched in google but i'm was a little confused.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic link, please provide explanation. did you try django rest's routers?

Comment: There isn't much info you properly provide you with good answer. By 'dynamic', and 'unique' what to you mean? You can edit your answer giving example of blog post title and links you want for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer is:

steps:
in views:

```
def article_content_view(request,article_id):
content = Article.objects.get(id=article_id).content
context = {
    'content':content
}
return render(request,'article.html',context)
```

in urls:

```
path('article/<int:article_id>/', views.article_content_view,name= 'article_content'),
```

in template html file:

```
<a href="{% url 'article_content' article.article_id %}"</a>
```

and my problem solved by add an id for each post in view:

```
'article_id': article.pk
```

you can see my [github repo](https://github.com/mehransdt/blogpy) for this project.

Answer (score 0):

The answer involves setting a slug on your model instance, then referencing it within your URL, and then consuming it in your view in order to determine what blog post to pass into your context. Honestly, this is unfortunately a loaded question, but one that is gone over in pretty much any starter tutorial on Django.

Check out this video as it covers exactly what you're asking (he's building a blog).
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bmvd1O5pNIY

Comment: I succeeded to build views and url pattern. routes are work successfully if typing it in address bar like this: 127.0.0.1:8000/article/2 . but now i need to create hreft tag and link it to routes. i wrote <a href="{% url 'article_content' article.id %}" but i have error.

Comment: Show us what you added to urls.py

Answer (score -1):

you can get a unique random URL by using

```
import uuid
x = uuid.uuid4().hex
```

get this link in localhost:8000/?url=x

in urls.py
add path in urlpatterns

```
path(<url>/,viewname)
```